Quintic del Pezzo Surface and Lines intersecting it
A question about an aspect of Francesco Polizzi's construction in this MO answer:
Let $X$ be a del Pezzo quintic surface with anticanonical embedding $X \subset \mathbb{P}^5$ (i.e. imbedded via linear system $\vert -K_X \vert $ of the ample (because del Pezzo by definition Fano) anticanonical line bundle $-K_X$) and project it from a general point to $\mathbb{P}^4$. [...]
Then he made a claim I not understand:

[...] and that appears since there exists exactly one line $\ell \cong \Bbb P^1 \subset \mathbb{P}^5$ which intersect $X$ at more than one point.

Question: Why & how to see this?
More precisely so there are two questions: Why if a line $\Bbb P^1 \subset \mathbb{P}^5$ intersects $X$ non trivially and is not contained in it, it intersects in at most $2$ points,
and why generically it even intersects in only one point with exactly one exception?
More generally, what can be said more generally about intersectional relation/bahavior of lines  $\Bbb P^1 \subset \mathbb{P}^5$ and  $X \subset \mathbb{P}^5$?

You misunderstood; in the linked answer only lines passing through a given general point of $\mathbb{P}^5$ are considered, and among those, indeed, there is only one line intersecting $X$ at two points.
In general there are two simple fact.
Fact 1. $X$ is an intersection of quadrics, therefore if for a line $L$ the scheme $X \cap L$ has length at least three, then $L$ is contained in every quadric containing $X$, and hence $L \subset X$.
Fact 2. $X$ is a linear section on $\mathrm{Gr}(2,5)$:
$$
X = \mathrm{Gr}(2,5) \cap \mathbb{P}^5.
$$
It follows from this that $\mathbb{P}^5$ is covered by secant lines to $X$. Indeed, if
$$P \in \mathbb{P}^5 \subset \mathbb{P}(\wedge^2\Bbbk^5)
$$
is a point of the Plucker space, and if it does not lie on $X$, it corresponds to a non-decomposable bivector, which belongs to the projectivization of $\mathbb{P}(\wedge^2\Bbbk^4)$ for some $\Bbbk^4 \subset \Bbbk^5$, and every line in $\mathbb{P}(\wedge^2\Bbbk^4)$ is a secant to the sub-Grassmannian $\mathrm{Gr}(2,4) \subset \mathrm{Gr}(2,5)$ (moreover, secant lines to $\mathrm{Gr}(2,5)$ are exactly the lines contained in various subspaces $\mathbb{P}(\wedge^2\Bbbk^4)$). It remains to note that
$$
\mathbb{P}(\wedge^2\Bbbk^4) \cap \mathbb{P}^5
$$
is a line in $\mathbb{P}^5$ passing through $P$, which must be secant to $X$. Moreover, it follows that this line is unique, unless the above intersection is a plane, hence $P$ belongs to the linear span of a conic on $X$.

Ad Fact 1 that del Pezzo quintic surface is given as intersection of quadrics, the argument for this is exactly that one you gave here in comments, right? (Just for those who may read this at later time)

No, there we discussed del Pezzo surfaces of degree 2 (and in the double anticanonical embedding), and here we talk about del Pezzo surfaces of degree 5 (in the anticanonical embedding).

Oh I see, sorry, so here we cannot expect to have representation of $X$ as $Y \cap Q$ as there. But how to see then in this context that the quintic del Pezzo $X$ is given as intersection of quadics as you claim in Fact 1?

Because its hyperplane section, an elliptic curve of degree 5, is an intersection of quadrics.

That its hyperplane section is elliptic curve follows just from adjunction formula (...as it was assumed to be quintic), and that degree $5$ is obvious, but how to see that this hyperplane section is intersection of quadrics? Do we need to invoke somehow its explicit Weierstrass form(which available for almost all elliptic curves up to char $p\neq 2,3$ issue I think)? Or can one see it more "directly"?

(cont) Not sure, an idea: so once we know that hyperplane section $E:=X \cap H \subset \Bbb P^5$ is an elliptic curve of degree $5$, we maybe can try to find rational projection $p_M: \Bbb P^4 \dashrightarrow \Bbb P^2$ from appropriate plane $M =\Bbb P^2$ restricting to an iso on $E$ such that $p_M(E)$ becomes quadric in $\Bbb P^2$. Does it help somehow to see that $E \subset \Bbb P^5$ is intersection of quadrics?

#Update: Or, think I got it: The embedding $X \cap H \subset H \cong \Bbb P^4$ induce by ampleness surjections $f_n:\Gamma(H,O_H(n) \to (-K_X \vert _{X \cap H})^{\otimes n}$ for all $n$. Then for $n=2$ we consider the vspace of quadrics containing $X \cap H$, aka kernel of $f_2$. Then if $2$ quadrics contain it, their intersection must be whose $X \cap H$ by Bezout & from degree reasons. That's the trick, right?

*whole $X \cap H$ by taking "test intersection" with a general hyperplane in $H$
